# Get Bone directions

Tags: python

As far as i was able to notice,
there is option to get the direction of the bone using bone.vector .

what if i want to know the side or up vector of the bone ?
There is at-least option to get the points of the box that represent the bone
transform , so i will able to calculate it my self ?

Happy new year !
thank you all for the help!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

found my answer here :
from :
https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.PoseBone.html?highlight=bone#bpy.types.PoseBone.bone

x_axis

```
Vector pointing down the x-axis of the bone. (readonly)
```

y_axis

```
Vector pointing down the y-axis of the bone. (readonly)
```

z_axis

```
Vector pointing down the z-axis of the bone. (readonly)
```

(old)
work around :
I will just stick box \ line on the center of the bone,
then will use the box points for the directions calculation .

[image]